# Disable all check boxes inside a table with jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I need to disable all the check boxes inside a table cell when clicking on a hyperlink inside the same table.

I'm using the following jquery code to select all the check boxes nested inside the table.

```
$el = $(this).parents('table:eq(0)')[0].children('input[type="checkbox"]');
$($el).attr('checked', true);
```

For some reason this piece of code is not working.

Can anyone show me how to fix it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$('table input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled','true');
```

if you have an id for the table

```
$('table#ID input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled','true');
```

Comment: I have noticed that one should take write true and not 'true'. This works : $('table input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled',true) but not this : $('table input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled','true');

Comment: Helped me out and saved me from writing up a question. Thank you. +1

Answer (score 6):

Disable?

```
$("a.clickme").click(function(){
  $(this)                    // Link has been clicked
    .closest("td")           // Get Parent TD
    .find("input:checkbox")  // Find all checkboxes
    .attr("disabled", true); // Disable them
});
```

or Checked?

```
$("a.clickme").click(function(){
  $(this)                    // Link has been clicked
    .closest("td")           // Get Parent TD
    .find("input:checkbox")  // Find all checkboxes
    .attr("checked", false); // Uncheck them
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be a lot simpler:

```
$el = $(this).parents('table:eq(0)')[0].children('input[type="checkbox"]');
```

Could be:

```
$el = $(this).parents('table:first :checkbox');
```

Then to disable them:

```
$el.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

or to check them:

```
$el.attr('checked', 'checked');
```

or to uncheck them:

```
$el.removeAttr('checked');
```

or to enable them:

```
$el.removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

See also: [selector/checkbox](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checkbox)

```
jQuery("#hyperlink").click(function() {
  jQuery('#table input:checkbox').attr('disabled', true);
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

// Enable/Disable All Checkboxes

```
$('#checkbox').click(function() {

    var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
    var checkboxes = '.checkboxes input[type=checkbox]';

    if (checked) {
        $(this).attr('checked','checked');
        $(checkboxes).attr('disabled','true');
    } else {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        $(checkboxes).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
// Action sur le checkbox
        $("#tabEmployes thead tr th:first input:checkbox").click(function() {
            var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
            $("#tabEmployes tbody tr td:first-child input:checkbox").each(function() {
                $(this).prop('checked',checked);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

------------------------------- HTML Code below ------------------------------

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="callFunction()" value="Click" />
```

------------------------------- JQuery Code below -----------------------------

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function callFunction() {
        //:
        $('table input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', 'true');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, after clicking on button, you will see that when this JS function will call, all the four check-boxes will become disabled. Thanks.